# GPU RAM occupied but no PIDs

Tags: gpu, nvidia, ram

The `nvidia-smi` shows following indicating 3.77GB utilized on GPU0 but no processes are listed for GPU0:

```
(base) ~/.../fast-autoaugment$ nvidia-smi
Fri Dec 20 13:48:12 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.50       Driver Version: 430.50       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN Xp            Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   34C    P8     9W / 250W |   3771MiB / 12196MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  TITAN Xp            Off  | 00000000:84:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 38%   62C    P8    24W / 250W |   2295MiB / 12188MiB |      8%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    1      1910      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           105MiB |
|    1      2027      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          51MiB |
|    1      3086      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          1270MiB |
|    1      3237      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         412MiB |
|    1     30593      G   /proc/self/exe                               286MiB |
|    1     31849      G   ...quest-channel-token=4371017438329004833   164MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Similarly `nvtop` shows same GPU RAM utilization but the processes it lists shows `TYPE=Compute` and if you try to kill PIDs it shows then you get error:

```
(base) ~/.../fast-autoaugment$ kill 27761
bash: kill: (27761) - No such process
```

How to reclaim GPU RAM occupied by apparently ghost processes?

Answer (score 24):

Use following command to get insight into ghost processes occupying GPU RAM:

```
sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*
```

In my case, output is:

```
(base) ~/.../fast-autoaugment$ sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/nvidia0:        shitals     517 F.... nvtop
                     root       1910 F...m Xorg
                     gdm        2027 F.... gnome-shell
                     root       3086 F...m Xorg
                     shitals    3237 F.... gnome-shell
                     shitals   27808 F...m python
                     shitals   27809 F...m python
                     shitals   27813 F...m python
                     shitals   27814 F...m python
                     shitals   28091 F...m python
                     shitals   28092 F...m python
                     shitals   28096 F...m python
```

This shows processes that nvidia-smi as well as nvtop fails to shows. After I killed all of the `python` processes, the GPU RAM was freed up.

Another thing to try is to reset GPU using the command:

```
sudo nvidia-smi --gpu-reset -i 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to do this programmatically in python if all the processes you want to kill have a common substring in their name (USE CAUTION, add sudo if desired).

```
import subprocess

process_name_substring = 'python'

result = subprocess.run(['fuser', '/dev/nvidia0', '-v'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

process_ids = [int(i) for i in str(result.stdout).split(' ') if i.isdigit()]

for process_id in process_ids:
    pid_info = subprocess.run(['ps', '-p', str(process_id)], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    
    if process_name_substring in str(pid_info.stdout):
        kill_output = subprocess.run(['kill', '-9', str(process_id)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Shital Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207661/shital-shah) mentioned, you can use the fuser command to inspect which zombie processes are running on your GPUs:

```
sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*
```

In case you do not want to reset your GPU because you've got other processes running on it, I've used [Chaitanya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2031870/chaitanya)'s script as a basis and added a bit more functionality on top of it to allow killing only processes by specific users on specific GPU cores.

Usage:

```
python3 script.py gpu_number process_name user_name
```

Code:

```
import argparse
import subprocess


def get_num_gpus():
    result = subprocess.run(['nvidia-smi', '-L'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    gpu_info = result.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip()
    num_gpus = len(gpu_info.split('\n'))  # each line corresponds to one GPU
    return num_gpus


def main(args):
    process_name_to_kill = args.process_name
    user_name = args.user_name
    gpu_number = args.gpu_number

    num_gpus = get_num_gpus()
    print(f'Number of GPUs: {num_gpus}')
    if gpu_number >= num_gpus or gpu_number < 0:
        print(f'GPU #{gpu_number} does not exist')
        return

    print(f'Scanning GPU #{gpu_number} processes')
    result = subprocess.run(['fuser', '/dev/nvidia' + str(gpu_number), '-v'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    result_str = result.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip()

    process_ids = [int(i) for i in result_str.split(' ') if i.isdigit()]
    for process_id in process_ids:
        pid_info = subprocess.run(['ps', '-p', str(process_id), '-o', 'comm=', '-o', 'user='], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        process_info = pid_info.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip().split()
        process_name = process_info[0]
        owner = process_info[1]
        print(f"PID: {process_id}, Process name: {process_name}, User: {owner}")
        if process_name_to_kill in process_name and owner == user_name:
           kill_output = subprocess.run(['kill', '-9', str(process_id)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            print(f'killed process with id {process_id}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('gpu_number', type=int, help='GPU number to scan')
    parser.add_argument('process_name', help='Name of the process to kill')
    parser.add_argument('user_name', help='Name of the user who owns the process')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```