# Zombie process does not allow deallocating GPU memory

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, zombie-process

I am loading NLP models in GPU to do inferencing.
But once the inference is over the GPU does not deallocate its memory:

[image: nvidia-smi image]

But then the command `ps -a | grep python` gave me

[image: ps -a image]

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a similar problem, a pytorch process on the GPU became zombie and left GPU memory used. Furthermore, in my case the process showed 100% usage in the GPU (`GPU-util` in the `nvidia-smi` output). **The only solution I have found so far is rebooting the system.**

In case you want to try other solutions, I tried before rebooting (without succeed):

- Killing the parent of the zombie process: see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/201308/813219). After this, the child zombie process became child of `init` (pid=1). `init` should reap zombie processes automatically, but this did not happen in my case (the process could still be found with `ps`, and the gpu memory was not freed).
- Sending `SIGCHLD` to `init` (command: `kill -17 1`), to force reaping, but `init` still did not reap the process, and the gpu memory remained being used.
- As suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431784/gpu-ram-occupied-but-no-pids/59431785#59431785), I checked other child processes that may be related and using the GPU: `fuser -v /dev/nvidia*`, but no other python processes were found in my case (other than the original zombie process).
- As suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4293#issuecomment-409823141), killing processes that are accessing `/dev/nvidia0`, by running `fuser -k /dev/nvidia0`. This did not affect the zombie process.
- Clearing the gpu with nvidia-smi: `nvidia-smi --gpu-reset -i <device>`, but this throwed `device is currently being used by one or more other processes... Please first kill all processes using this device...`

At the end, the only solution was rebooting the system.

I'm not sure what caused the error in the first place. I had a pytorch script training in a single GPU, and I have used the same script many times without issue. I used a `Dataloader` using `num_workers=5`, which I suspect may have been the culprit, but I cannot be sure. The process suddenly just hang, without throwing an exception or anything, and left the GPU unusable.

I'm using versions: pytorch `1.7.1+cu110`, nvidia-driver 455.45.01, running in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I killed all python processes (pkill python), and zombies are no more on the GPU. I was using torch.