# "No Such Process" consumes GPU memory

Tags: linux, nvidia

When I use `nvidia-smi`, I found nearly 20GB GPU Memory is missing somewhere (total listed processes took 17745MB, meanwhile Memory-Usage is 37739MB):

[image]

Then I use `nvitop`, you can see `No Such Process` has actually taken my GPU resources. However, I cannot kill this PID:

```
>>> sudo kill -9 118238
kill: (118238): No such process
```

[image]

How can I get rid of this ghost process without interupting others?

Answer (score 13):

I have found the solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59431785/6563277.

First, I run `sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*` to see all processes are using my GPU RAM that `nvidia-smi` has failed to show.

Then, I saw some "ghost" Python processes. And after killing it, the GPU RAM was free up.

Comment: To  just kill all python processes: `pkill -9 python3`

Comment: that didn't work all the time... `pkill .py` kills all python processes a different way!